# Linear Algebra equivalent of Paul's Online Math Notes (Lamar)

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning, online-resources

I'm not sure if this is question is a better fit for the main site or the meta site, but I was wondering if there are any beginner-friendly websites to learn linear algebra, similar to [Paul's online math notes](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/) (which focuses more on calculus). I like that website because I can learn at my own pace and browse the content, they also provide a lot of practice problems and problem sets.

Khan Academy is too noisy a website to my liking, though I don't doubt that their content is very qualitative. I just prefer something less fancy but maybe with more extensive problem sets to get some practice in.

I'm mostly interested in learning linear algebra for its practicality in writing mathematical and engineering software, but I also would like to learn more about the theoretical side of things so that I don't just learn algorithms and solution methods in a complete vacuum.

Comment: I think it might be useful to qualify whether there is a broader purpose you have in mind for learning linear algebra, besides enrichment. From my own experiences, you can study linear algebra with a focus on its *computational* aspects, or on more *pure mathematical* aspects. The former might be exemplified by Gilbert Strang's *Linear Algebra* texts, which is often used in engineering, economics, computer science education, whereas the latter is exemplified by Sheldon Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* or Paul Halmos' *Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces* is often used for mathematics majors.

Comment: I've seen a couple of Strang's MIT lectures on open courseware, and they indeed seemed more pragmatic than theoretic (albeit a bit chaotic sometimes). As for Axler and Halmos's textbooks, I haven't looked into them but I don't believe that a more theoretical foundation is necessarily incompatible with a more computational approach (unless it's waaay too abstract and esoteric). Thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: I found the treatment here for the theory good (better than Axler in some ways): https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/notes/linear-algebra-notes/. As for the applied part, the book "Numerical Linear Algebra" by Trefethen and Bau is supposedly good, but I have not read it.

Comment: Thanks Mason, I'll check it out!